# Why needing of escaping any backslashes used in the path to the file on Windows

Tags: windows, file, path, escaping

Why is there a needing to escape any backslashes used in the path to the file on Windows?

Like `c:\\folder\\resource.txt` instead of just `c:\folder\resource.txt`

Comment: Well, you somehow answered yourself. The phrase "escape" is key here so read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: It isn't Windows that needs the backslash escaped.  Unless you wanted to ask about a *specific* programming language or other context in which escaping backslashes is necessary, I think this question is too broad.